# Is there some way to get all the text of a document into the clipboard?

Tags: copy-paste, ipados, file-conversion

I cannot select all text to copy to the clipboard on the Apple iPad I have so is there some way, like on an online website or an app, to get all the text from a document into the clipboard so that I can paste the text in an area that only allows clipboard contents?

Comment: What type of document/which app is this? Does the app actively prevent you from selecting or is it just cumbersome to scroll through the whole doc to extend the selection?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>and then <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> should copy all of the text in a text field on macOS and iOS and iPadOS. You can use the pop up “Select All” and “Copy” pop up as well in most apps.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/select-and-edit-text-ipadac2fea3c/ipados

If you’re not getting enough text, then it’s the problem of the app not placing it all in the same field to be copied. We would need to know more about from which app you are copying to proceed down that path.

If the text is several chapters long or has embedded objects, that can also run into issues since a pasteboard can have multiple objects the app receiving the past has to check and deal with multiple objects, but for most reasonable pasteboard operations, I’ve never run into unexpected issues or been disappointed on pasting thousands of words of plain text on my iPad. [I think pasteboard can contain billions of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6482761/475228) and we run out of memory on device before the copy / paste fails us.